# putting mysql query into array and using more than once error

Tags: php

I have a real big problem that normally doesn't happen. For some reason on this occasion it errors...

Ok I put in a mysql query IE

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from tablename");
```

Then i say

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_BOTH)
```

When I put (even a blank loop in it gives me an error) a loop in... 
IE

```
foreach ($row as $rowme){
 // do nothing
   echo $rowme['id'] . "<br />";
}
```

I get invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Never before has this happened - any ideas why it is now?

Running PHP 5.2.11 on the server

`while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc)` = works fine, but I can use this only once on the page... another question why can't I use the same loop again somewhere else? (Coldfusion you can use the same loop from a query repeatedly? why does not PHP do this using `mysql_fetch_assoc`???)

I'm using a jQuery photo gallery, which populates some repeated javascript to write the descriptions on the images via the class and repeats the list items they are in, hence I need two loops of the same query. So obviously putting the query results into an array and using the array repeatedly should work right?

The only other option is to create two queries exactly the same. Seems inefficient however.

Can anyone answer these questions or shed some light. I'm desperate and very very behind putting in this gallery, (why I'm still here at work at 1.22 am) - Would be most grateful.

Thanks

A.

Comment: Ok so I gather that if the query returns no results it wont populate the for loop and throw the toys out the pram. errrgh... so checking mysql_num_rows before hand might help prevent the error.

Comment: @Andi I have tried to make your question readable. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting help with things like your code blocks and samples. The easier you make it to read the more likely some one is to answer it. If you can't be bothered to type it up properly then why should we bother answering?

Comment: you should post the actual block of code you tried to use

Comment: if you dont already, then remember to connect to the server when you use mysql_query.

Comment: Please pick one question at a time.

Comment: Thanks. @Treffynnon - BTW I didn't see the code block buttons when entering the question as am new to the forum. I'm in a hurry as I've been up working since 5am on the website coz the client wanted it up yesterday, @8am this morning I was decorating Penny Hill Park hotel. I was at Home at 6pm and 7.30pm until now I've been programming again. So please forgive me for being neive but I'm nackered, and I my aunt passed away this morning so I've had a bad day. Please forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to your "dilemma". You cannot query the results twice in PHP without telling explicitly.

But a simple option is to store them away into an array:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from tablename");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $saved[] = $row;
}
```

This allows you to use the result set twice, and also makes your example foreach construct work:

```
foreach ($saved as $rowme){
     echo $rowme['id'] . "<br />";
```

Obviously only advisable if it's few result rows.

---

The second option is to "rewind" the results. So you can actually query with _fetch_assoc twice:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from tablename");

// first time
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    ...
}


// other code here
...


// second iteration over results
mysql_data_seek($query, 0);   // rewind
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    ...
}
```

See http://php.net/mysql_data_seek in the manual.

Comment: Oh on a second note guys, you know I've never used the function mysql_data_seek... that seems like the solution for me to check out. Although I know I could build an array for each item, although it would probably end up being a multidimensional array. The image gallery is made of two tables, porftolio_folders and portfolio_items, filtered by a url variable in the SQL. So if I was to create an array I would probably have to make a multidimensional array IE - $rowitem[0][0] = image, $row[0][1] = description and so on... I like the rewind best. Thanks again for all your helps!

Answer (score 2):

> `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc)` = works fine, but I can use this only once on the page...

Not so; you could write `if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(...))` as many times as you like.

However in your case, you probably want to use [the "seek" functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) that let you go back to the start of the resultset if you want to iterate it again.

> I get invalid argument supplied for foreach()

You never checked that `$row` is an array. If there are no results, `$row` will be `FALSE`.

Comment: Ok That's great. sorry v. tired a long day, and being completely thick. I kinda guessed that the array had zero results and was having a fit, but then I didn't check to see if $row was an array. However Q. If you specified $row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM) - wouldn't that be specifying the resultset as an array in the first place? Why should you need to check again if its an array if you already classified that it was.

Comment: @Andi: You didn't classify that it's an array. You asked the MySQL API to give you an array, but if you [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) you'll see that it returns `FALSE` if there are no results. You should read the documentation for _any_ function if you don't know what it does, before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array there it the way that you build the array with your stream.

```
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

But when you do this you need a lot of memory and when your array is to big and you come over the the momory_limit which you can define in the **php.ini** you get an error like

"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxxxxxx bytes exh..."

Comment: As you indicate, this is usually wrong. It's silly to drag all the results into memory and then operate on them as a block, when you can iterate through the resultset properly.

Comment: Yeah see I normally use mysql_fecth_assoc over a while loop for this reason, although I had the problem of using it twice and didn't want to specify the query twice.(probably the only nice thing about coldfusion is that the query is returned as an object and you can loop this as much as you want).

Answer (score 1):

I think you slightly misunderstand what each mysql function does.  both the names you've chosen and the way you try to use them show this.

I'll try to show an example with descriptive variable names.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";   //$query is sql query
$res = mysql_query($quwey);           //$res is resource
```

A resource encapsulates the results of the query.  You use `mysql_fetch` functions to get data out.  I'll use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get one row at a time but `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_object` are fine too.  Every time it gets called you get one row.  `while` loops are a good choice for this bc they will fetching and re-assigning the new rows until there are none left.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) //$row is an associative array for single row.  
                                      //one element for every field of table
{
   var_dump($row); //this will show you what $row looks like
}
```

You can iterate on `$row` with `foreach`, it will step thru every element of `$row`.  That is, every field for a single row of the table.  This will NOT visit more than one row.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{
   //$row['id'] makes sense
   foreach($row as $fieldName=>$fieldValue)
   {
       echo "$fieldName -> $fieldValue <br />;
       //$fieldName['id'] and $fieldValue['id'] do not make sense. they are not arrays
   }
}
```

You were concerned that you can only use that while/fetch thing once, but thats not the case.  You can reset the resource's pointer back to the top and do the while loop all over again:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {//do stuff}
 mysql_data_seek($res, 0); //reset pointer back to top
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {//do stuff again}
```

Or you can store all of the rows into one (multidimensional) array you can work with later as many times as you like.

```
$arrayOfRows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) //$row is a single row.  one element for every field of table
{
   $arrayOfRows[] = $row;
}

var_dump($arrayOfRows); //see what this looks like
```

And this is how you can loop thru this `$arrayOfRows` and use it later.

```
foreach($arrayOfRows as $oneRow)
{
    foreach($oneRow as $fieldName=>$fieldValue)
    {
         //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi There thanks. I do already use the example you mentioned of looping through an array.. for example...

Comment: Hi There thanks. I do already use the example you mentioned of looping through an array.. for example... my code for sorting a nested menu in the cms uses array keys and values from an array populated from a $_GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is directly linked to the number of results. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) you can see the return type is either an array or FALSE. The latter might give you the error you are describing.

Fix it with either mysql_num_rows() or

```
if($row){
    foreach ($row as $rowme){
        // do nothing
        echo $rowme['id'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```